# Compare IDs and and see if names are the same excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a workbook in excel and I am trying to compare ID's and see if there names are the same.

basically i have two list and want to see if there is any miss match in them. checking for inconsistency.

Im trying to see if the names match with the First / Last name.

possibly bring back the names if they match or phones.

I tried a HLookup, but can seem to get it right or even close to work.

```
 =HLOOKUP(C2,J2:J300,H2:I300,TRUE)
 $A         $B               $C        $D
 First Name Last Name   Ext      Phone
 Joe        Test        1100     14965231235
Joe         Test2       1101     14965231233


 $H         $I               $J        $K
First Name  Last Name   Ext      Phone
 Joe        Test        1100     14965231235
Mike        Test2       1101     14965231233
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me get back the First Name.
=INDEX(K:K,MATCH(C8,J:J,0))

Example from:
https://www.excel-university.com/how-to-return-a-value-left-of-vlookups-lookup-column/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first cell under the **First Name** header is in cell A2, and the first cell for the second table under the **First Name** header is in cell H2, you can try this. This will highlight the cells in red if they are different:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With ws
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lrow
            For j = 1 To 4
                If .Cells(i, j).Value <> .Cells(i, j + 7).Value Then
                    .Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 255
                    .Cells(i, j + 7).Interior.Color = 255
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```